# do I need kube-proxy and vpc-cni addons when running fargate only eks cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

they both seem like good add-ons when you're running node groups; I'm assuming given Fargate mandates ALB's would register IP only for services, and other similar fargate requirements, do we still need these two add-ons?

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question is old, but I ended here searching for answers and asked AWS since I found no info about this online. I'm posting their answer in case someone else ends here in the future.

> To begin with, The Amazon VPC CNI plugin for Amazon EKS is installed on fargate nodes by default and its management ( networking and IP address management ) is handled by the control plane ( by AWS).

> Generally speaking, when using fargate profiles, add-ons such as VPC CNI and kube-proxy don’t need to be manually added by you as they are automatically deployed upon creation of EKS cluster on the fargate nodes and they’re fully managed by AWS which will save you the trouble to having to manage them yourself. It is also good to know that fargate doesn’t support  DaemonSets.

Comment: thanks, how about coredns? no need too, right?

Comment: Coredns does not come bundled in the fargate hosts! I think that is becaus it is not a daemonset and it's not a requirement for kubernetes.

I've never done it but I read that you can spin up a Kubernetes cluster without clusterDNS, but you won't have service name resolutions and stuff like that :D